# How to disable cxf SOAP client use multipart request

Tags: java, soap, cxf, multipart, cxf-client

I have to call a proprietary service that does not support multipart requests, I'm not sending any attachments but cxf seems to create a multipart request

```
POST /endpoint HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="text/xml"; boundary="uuid:86ebef4f-fc2a-431b-a21b-37e86b4901f9"; start="<root.message@cxf.apache.org>"; start-info="text/xml"
Accept: */*
Authorization: Basic U1dHMTAwNTA6MTIzNDU1
SOAPAction: "XYZ.0050"
User-Agent: Apache-CXF/3.3.6
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Host: localhost:8082
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2134


--uuid:86ebef4f-fc2a-431b-a21b-37e86b4901f9
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>
[etc...]
```

I've noticed a non-multipart request works fine

```
POST /endpoint HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Authorization: Basic U1dHMTAwNTA6MTIzNDU1
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8082
Pragma: no-cache
SOAPAction: "XYZ.0050"
User-Agent: Apache-CXF/3.3.6
Content-Length: 2114

[etc...]
```

How do I force cxf to use a non-multipart request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like cxf creates a multipart any time there is a `@XmlAttachmentRef` / `DataHandler` attribute, in my case it is never used so I removed it from my classes.

a better solution would be to remove the `SwAOutInterceptor` from the interceptor chain by definining an interceptor remover

```kotlin
class InterceptorRemover : AbstractSoapInterceptor(Phase.PRE_LOGICAL) {
    init {
        addBefore(SwAOutInterceptor::class.java.name)
    }
    override fun handleMessage(message: SoapMessage?) {
        if (message != null) {
            val res = message.interceptorChain.firstOrNull() { it is SwAOutInterceptor }
            if (res != null) {
                message.interceptorChain.remove(res)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and add it to the chain:

```kotlin
val client = ClientProxy.getClient(port)
client.outInterceptors.add(InterceptorRemover())
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it didn't work for me. I need to send a request to retrieve a file (so I can't remove the DataHandler elements). But the request can't be a multipart content-type. Removing the SwAOutInterceptor doesn't seem to work. I've tried this with both POJO & PAYLOAD message-types. Am I missing something?